# expected shortfall and value-at-risk

Tags: quantiles, finance, extreme-value, risk

I once read a R example of computing `Value-at-Risk` and `expected shortfall` as follows

```
p = c(0.5,0.1,0.05,0.025,0.01,0.001)

VaR = qnorm(p)

ES = dnorm(qnorm(p))/p
```

I am not sure why the expected shortfall can be calculated this way?

Comment: This appears to have little or nothing to do with [conventional meanings of VaR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk).  What source are you using for this `R` code?

Comment: The book of Financial Risk Forecasting, written by Jon Danielsson

Comment: We need an accurate quotation and a clear description of the context, because clearly something is amiss here.

Comment: Are you talking about the code just before section 5.4? You might like to include the couple of lines of mathematics on which it is based, and define the variables..